# How to fix svnadmin: E720123: Can't open file...... During a dump

Tags: svn

I am trying to do a dump of a repo and I think the issue is that there is an ampersand in the file path. I have tried ^& and I have tried putting quotes around the file path and I have tried both together. I keep getting an error with the Format file that is in the repo. Dumping all the other repos (they all have the Format file) caused me no issues.

svnadmin: E720123: Can't open file 'Z:\Subversion\Build Files & Templates" \Format': The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

```
svnadmin dump "Z:\Subversion\Build Files & Templates\" > "Z:\Subversion\Build Files & Templates_repository-backup.dmp"
```

I ended up doing this and it works. The ending \ I think was the main problem.

```
svnadmin dump "Z:\Subversion\Build Files "^&" Templates" > "Z:\Subversion\Build Files "^&" Templates_repository-backup.dmp"
```

Answer (score 1):

It's either the directory "Build Files & Templates" does not contain a repository (it is a working copy maybe?) or the path you specify to dump is invalid (make sure there are not extra characters, e.g. extra double quotes).

Comment: It is definitely a repo and I copied the path directly from windows explorer.

Comment: @xRuhRohx show us the list of items in Z:\Subversion\Build Files & Templates\

Comment: I added them up above

Comment: @xRuhRohx Take a closer look at the path in the error. It has extra " sign and a whitespace: `Z:\Subversion\Build Files & Templates" \Format`.

Comment: But I can't figure out why it is doing that.  I am running the dump command exactly as I posted it above.  :(

Answer (score 1):

To avoid dealing with escape characters in the future and generally circumvent this issue, you can rename the repository so that the path doesn't include an &. I also recommend avoiding spaces. Stick to letters, numbers, and select special characters ("_", "-", and "."). Of course renaming the repository means that all existing references to it will need to be modified. For working copies, use [svn relocate](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/vi/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.relocate.html).